# Инструменты web-программиста

Tags: php, веб-программирование, denwer

В университете для разработки сайтов использовался Denwer. Ответьте те кто работал в web-e (естественно не в вузе): что реально используется **на работе** для имитации рабочей среды (если как я понимаю используется один компьютер на стадии предварительной разработки до помещения на реальный сервер)? Хочется увидеть много ответов, чтобы представлять, что **реально используется на работе** и **также хотелось бы знать навязывает ли работадатель определенные инструменты или же предоставляет свободу выбора в этом вопросе**.

Comment: Всё можно легко настроить отдельно же.

Answer (score 5):

У всех разработчиков на компьютерах стоят виртуальные машины, на которых установлена и настроена ОС максимально близко к production-серверу. Никаких denwer, wasp и т.д. Окружение должно быть максимально одинаковым везде.

Перед обновлением программы на production-сервере, программа проходит тестирование на нескольких серверах, которые по конфигурации и настройке идентичны production-серверу.

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится wamp (если у вас windows, конечно), http://www.wampserver.com/ru/ сразу в комплекте настроенный phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Олег Б вы используете wamp на работе?

Comment: Да........

Comment: @Олег Б а что по поводу предоставления свободы в выборе инструментов работадателем?

Comment: @ivan89 выбор основных инструментов (операционная система, IDE и тд) практически всегда остается за работодателем - вряд ли кому-то нужен программист, корчащий из себя рок-звезду и заявляющий, что по религиозным убеждениям он отказывается работать с %подставить название%. Особенно если этот программист не имеет вообще никакого опыта работы.  Если же говорить о каких-то менее основополагающих вещах, то тут обычно допускается некая свобода выбора.

Comment: Обычный офисный пк с fullhd разрешением монитора + wamp + notepad++ => ну назовите хоть одну причину почему этого может не хватить?

Comment: @DreamChild но если выбор работодателя основан не на знании какого-то программиста/технаря то думаю вполне можно поспорить с работодателем, на счет основных инструментов. К примеру, если лесорубу дадут пластмассовый топор...

Answer (score 2):

Для работы используется linux с установленными apache, mysql и php, это на рабочей машине разработчика. Для тестирования желательно иметь отдельный сервер (или виртуал хост) ну и продакшин сервер, оба естественно на linux (можно также freebsd или что-то в этом роде, но это уже на любителя).

Comment: Что мешает использовать Windows на рабочей машине разработчика? и почему отдельный сервер или продакшн сервер "естественно на linux"???

Comment: Linux зарекомендовал себя как более надёжное решение для серверов по сравнению с Windows. К тому же, на Linux не нужно приобретать лицензию, что удешевляет стоимость хостинга. А раз проект на продакшне будет работать под Linux, разработчику также лучше использовать Linux.

Comment: Потому что linux для этого предназначен, его можно просто использовать без каких либо костылей. Тот же ssh клиент для которого в windows жутко неудобные терминалы. А для установки нужных инструментов обычно хватает одной команды в консоли (например git, rsync, какой нибудь модуль к php). Сходу есть (или легко установить) интерпретаторы нужных языков python, ruby или nodejs. А некоторые инструменты на windows вообще затруднительно (если вообще возможно) установить, например какая нибудь очередь сообщений memcacheq, rabbitmq или zeromq.

Answer (score 2):

Работаю сразу с сервером (FileZilla, FTP, ssh, myadmin), что мешает то?

Answer (score 1):

У меня на работе:

1. Стоит сервер, на нем  Archi Linux, на нем Web сервер (какой, не знаю точно, не я его настраивал). Сервер держит мастер базу и сайт + debug базу с сайтом. Стоит Git, настроенный так, что при залитии на ветку debug сайт на дебаге сразу обновляется (изменяя при залитии различные параметры конфигураций), и то же самое происходит с мастер веткой.
2. У нас, разработчиков стоит винда. У меня OpenServer, у некоторых другой... Соответственно пишем, разрабатываем под своим сервером, потом заливаем на debug, там тестируем на работоспособность на основном сервере. И при выпуске новой версии - заливаем на мастера.

На счет свободы выбора:

Нормальное руководство **советуется с ведущим программистом**, который должен анализировать какие инструменты лучше подходят для данной задачи. А остальным эти инструменты будут навязываться.

Answer (score 1):

только Linux, Только хардкор! На витуалках ессно :)

Действительно, смотрите в сторону VM, в крупных компаних в любом случае все сервера (хосты точнее) живут на виртуалках, обычно разработчики этим не занимаются. Обычно разрабы чтото пишут, скидывают это в VCS и потом нажимают хитрую кнопку в к.-л. системе CI, где их код проходит всяческие тесты, билдится и потом выкладывается на dev хосты, где тестируется...

Вообщем очень зависит от компании, где вы будете работать, в любом случае, в компаниях есть корп "стиль" и набор программ, которые разрешены security службой...

Answer (score 1):

С недавнего времени использую свой сервер на Ubuntu Server в виртуальной машине.
Очень удобно, так как можно приравнять к реальному vds\vps.
Мана как поднять сервер на Ubuntu есть тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/139461/ 
Ну а установка бубунты под Virtual Box думаю труда не вызовет

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP - работает с флешки - удобно - всё в комплекте

Answer (score 0):

Использую Denwer на машинке с Windows так как для моих задач его более чем достаточно.
На ноуте стоит Ubuntu с поднятым LAMP.
Все прекрасно работает  и при переносе сайтов проблем не возникает.

Answer (score 0):

OpenServer

Answer (score 0):

Denwer и аналоги - используется самоуверенными или, наоборот, опытными программистами.

Дело в том, что Denwer не является полномасштабной имитацией рабочей среды и в реальной работе могут всплывать косячки (например, имхо, наиболее частый проблем - большие/маленькие буквы в путях, права на каталоги - так как в среде Windows и под Юнихами это вещи работают по-разному).

Мы стараемся использовать наиболее полноценную имитацию - на компьютере разработчика стоит именно то, что и на боевом сервере. Это позволяет упростить развертывание сайта на боевую систему, но и тут не обходится без косячков. Недавно переводили сайт в боевой режим, все вроде отлажено, но из-за мелочей (разницы в настройках боевого сервера и компьютера, используемого для разработки) провозились почти день.

Влияет ли работодатель на выбор ПО? По ситуации. Если Вы хотите работать в специализированной конторе, давно и серьезно занимающейся разработкой веб-сайтов, но у них наверняка есть какие-то свои технологии работы. И убедить работодателя в переходе на новую технологию будет непросто - нужно будет привести АРГУМЕНТЫ, а не просто Я ХОЧУ.

В мелких и неспециализированных конторах, как правило, просто нет времени у руководства отлаживать единообразную технологию работы - и тут кто во что горазд.

Answer (score 0):

windows с настроенным apache php и базой данных по выбору,настраиваешь сам ручками и ubuntu с тем же самым.Там и тестим.

Answer (score 0):

20 инструментов для разработчика

http://infoblog1.ru/tools/20-instrumentov